# Build errors with Ninja and Skia. Unable to find icudtl.dat even though the file exists

Tags: python, build, ninja, skia, gn

**Anyone know why i'm getting this error?**

```
[1/2620] copy ../../third_party/externals/icu/common/icudtl.dat icudtl.dat
FAILED: icudtl.dat
python E:/Development/c++/skia/skia/gn/cp.py ../../third_party/externals/icu/common/icudtl.dat icudtl.dat
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
ninja: fatal: ReadFile: The handle is invalid.
```

I looked for the file and it was in third_party/externals/icu/common/icudtl.dat

I used fetch to clone skia

My args.gn is

```
is_official_build               = true
is_debug                        = false
is_component_build              = false
skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo   = false
skia_use_system_libpng          = false
skia_use_system_libwebp         = false
skia_use_system_zlib            = false
skia_use_system_icu             = false
skia_use_system_harfbuzz        = false

cc          = "clang"
cxx         = "clang++"
clang_win   = "C:\Program Files\LLVM"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a very similar error and just finished debugging it.

You're getting an error on CreateProcess. The process it's trying to create right then is Python, so either you don't have Python installed or (more likely) the build system isn't looking for it in the right place. Run with the -v flag to see the actual error message and confirm this.

My error said that Python wasn't installed (it was) and I could get it from the Windows Store. I didn't bother fighting with the build system to figure out why it wasn't looking in the right spot and instead just installed the Windows Store version of Python, which fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late to answer, but might be helpful for one's looking through!
navigate to /Applications/Python/version/ and
click on Install Certificates.command
This would do.